# How to handle BufferedReader.readLine() goes to air and not return any value or exception in java?

Tags: java, sockets, communication, bufferedreader

I am reading a file through socket communication .

connection made.

while reading end of the file application hanged, it doesn't return any value/exception/null.still waiting for input.

How to handle this.

I tried the following code:

```
 is = clientsocket.getInputStream();

     // create new input stream reader
     isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

     // create new buffered reader
     br = new BufferedReader(isr);

     String value;

     // reads to the end of the stream 
     while((value = br.readLine()) != null)
     {
        // converts int to character
       // char c = (char)value;

        // prints character
        System.out.println(value);
        System.out.println(br.readLine());
     }
```

Comment: Are you sure server is sending hte EOF, please share the server code as well

Answer (score 1):

From one of the SO posts:

> The problem with just stopping where read would hang is that this can
>   happen in 2 cases:
>
> 1: server doesn't have any more data to send
>
> 2: The server has sent more data, but your client has not received it
>   yet due to network overload.
>
> And you only want to really stop reading in the first case, but you
>   want read to block in the second case.
>
> The way to solve this is to make a transfer protocol(Standard) which
>   allows the server to tell the client how much data it expects to send.
>
> If the server knows the total data size in advance, simply start by
>   sending the total number of bytes in the transfer, and then send the
>   data. That way the client knows when it have received all data.
>
> (Or the server can simply close the connection when done. That way
>   read should fail, but this only work if you don't need the connection
>   in the future)

Comment: Hi thanks for ur guidelines but the thing here the server is device. its not my control. i give command to read. it will return set of records to inputstream. then i ll use bufferedreader to read the data from the that.

this case what can i do ?

Comment: Then the only option is to know the length of packet stream